# How do I check If an element is inside an element? | Selenium | Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How do I check if an element is inside a specific tag, and NOT the entire document?

To give you an idea:

```
for child_element in parent_element:
          print(child_element)
```

Comment: Can you add an example when the check should pass and when the check should fail?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a parent element.

```
parent_element=driver.find_element((By.TAG_NAME,"ul"))
```

We can then access elements within that element by doing the following.

```
try:
    child_element=parent_element.find_element((By.XPATH,"./li"))
    print(child_element)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: am I supposed to substitute anything with by?

Comment: You can replace the By with anything. It's just an example of how to find elements inside a parent tag.